# How can I get what I edited when I run the game engine?

Tags: rendering, game-engine

I just want to know how do I get what I see when editing like in the picture below.

This is what I see in Edit Mode:
[image: Edit mode]

But some objects don't appear when I render it with the game engine:

[image: Game engine]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I'm not quite sure what you want.. Are you wondering why the red cubes aren't visible in the game engine?

Comment: Both the red cubes and the plane. I am currently following a tutorial video that most of the time leaves out helpful details. I have gotten a feel for blender but frustrating when the guy doing the video leaves out details. I am a web developer and use psd but animation altogether is new to me. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: At least with the current information I can't answer your question. It would be helpful if you share your .blend file and perhaps also the link to the tutorial.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYheb1v6ufQ

Comment: I was new to blender and maybe I missed out lighting... I will try that and let you know if that was it...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not have your material display setup correctly. At the bottom of you Blender window,just above the Time Line, you will see a Box the reads, "Object Mode". Next to this box will be a white ball. Left click this white ball and select Texture. Now when you press P to view your animation you should be able to see everything. You may also press the N key to bring out your right panel. There is a section there labeled Shading. Click on Shading and put a check next to "Textured Solid". Then click the box just above this and select from the list GLSL. This should work for you! Everyone that uses Blender goes through these gates which is needed if you will progress farther into the use of this Great Free Software. Persistence is the key to becoming great at using Blender. So do not give up! Just move forward! :O)